# Python: Tkinter iconbitmap assignment only works at module level

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I'm using a `tkinter.ttk` window and I'm using an icon to set the iconbitmap of my window. However `root.iconbitmap()` is ignored on Windows 10. But There is an easy way to avoid an error: `root.tkinter.call('wm', 'iconphoto', root._w, icon)`

So:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

root=Tk()
root.call('wm', 'iconphoto', root._w, icon)
```

works.
**BUT**:

```
def func():
    root=Tk()
    root.call('wm', 'iconphoto', root._w, icon)
```

does **NOT** work. An error occurs. It's interesting that that error is exactly the same one that occurs when you use `root.iconbitmap()`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\test.py", line 95, in <module>
func()
File "E:\test.py", line 36, in func
t.call('wm', 'iconphoto', t._w, icon)
_tkinter.TclError: can't use "pyimagex" as iconphoto: not a photo Image
```

And there is one interesting fact left: In another file I tried to use it as a function too, it worked. In the new file (`test.py`) it didn't work (and it was the same function). 
Does anybody know why it doesn't work and what I can do to avoid an error? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you show us where did you declared the `icon`?

Comment: `icon=PhotoImage(file=path)        # complete path name`

Comment: Ok correct me if I'm wrong, you want to create another window from a button or sort some of callback function while there's one window already running?

Comment: `root1=Toplevel(root)` doen't work too.

Comment: Then I tried this way, but dosen't seem to work...

Comment: Ok wait I post an answer this might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've a window opened already and wants to open another one with it's own icon then you should use `Toplevel()` instead of `Tk()` and to change the icon use

```
W2 = Toplevel()
icon = PhotoImage(file='icon.png')
W2.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', root._w, icon)
```

**Example:**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

def test():
    root = Toplevel()
    icon = PhotoImage( file='icon.png' )  # path to the icon
    root.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', root._w, icon)

r = Tk()

b =  Button(r, text='press', command=test)
b.pack()

mainloop()
```