# Tkinter - wont show picture

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, error-handling

I have a piece of Tkinter code that is part of a bigger program and I would like to insert a image `logon.gif` into that Tkinter window. But when I execute this code

```py
import PIL
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk

from tkinter import *


parent = Tk()
photo = PhotoImage(file="logon.gif")
w = Label(parent, image=photo)
w.photo = photo
w.pack()
parent.mainloop()
```

(which works in another program) it shows error msg:

```
`_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist`
```

Is it because I'm using tkinter in while loop in the program?
Here is the Code which makes error msg (I have functions there as well, but it's too long to paste it here as whole code)

```py
root = tk.Tk()
    photo = PhotoImage(file="logon.gif") # HERE
    w = Label(root, image=photo) #HERE
    root.title('Mirror')
    root.overrideredirect(True)
    root.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()))
    lab = Label(root, text="日本に \n ようこそ", font = ('', 40), bg='black', fg='white')
    lab.pack(anchor=SW, fill=X, padx=45)
    masterclock = tk.Label(root)
    masterclock.pack(anchor=NW, fill=X, padx=45)
    masterclock.configure(background='black')
    clock_frame = tk.Label(root, font = ('caviar dreams', 130), bg='black', fg='aqua')
    clock_frame.pack(in_=masterclock, side=LEFT)
    clock_frame2 = tk.Label(root, font = ('caviar dreams', 70), bg='black', fg='white')
    clock_frame2.pack(in_=masterclock, side=LEFT, anchor = N, ipady=15)

    msg = tk.Label(root, font = ('caviar dreams', 16), bg='black', fg='white')
    msg.pack(padx=5, pady=5, anchor=W)

    newstitle = tk.Label(root, font = ('caviar dreams', 30), bg='black', fg='white',wraplength=600)
    newstitle.pack(side=BOTTOM, anchor=W, fill=X)
    source = tk.Label(root, font = ('caviar dreams', 14), bg='black', fg='white',wraplength=600)
    source.pack(side=BOTTOM, anchor=W, fill=X)
    weatherr = tk.Label(root, font = ('caviar dreams', 14), bg='black', fg='white')
    weatherr.pack(side=TOP, anchor=E, fill=Y)
    w.photo = photo #HERE
    w.pack(side=TOP, anchor=W, fill=Y) #HERE

    msq()
    weathere()
    newsheader()
    tick()
    tickk()
    tock()
    display_next_item() # <- start displaying


    #root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
    root.configure(background='black')
    startupscreen.destroy()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I see two places where you create an instance of `Tk`. Is that really what you're doing? Unless you have a deep understanding of tkinter, you should only have a single instance.

Comment: Yes, I have a startupscreen = tk.Tk() before the while loop (as a program start screen)

Comment: Don't use `while` loop use `after()` and second of all if you have more than two `Tk` instances then that error will come as Bryan said, to fix that use all the secondary windows (children window) as `Toplevel()` [refer to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55769961/python-tkinter-iconbitmap-assignment-only-works-at-module-level/55773883#55773883)

Comment: `image "pyimage1" doesn't exist` - it can means common problem with `Garbage Collector`  (bug in module) which removes from memory `PhotoImage` created in function and assigned to local variable. You may have to use `global photo` before `photo = PhotoImage(...)` to resolve this problem (bug in module). effbot.org: [PhotoImage](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm)

Comment: thanks to all of you. Yes, problem was that second Tk() window, I changed name to Toplevel(), made some small changes and it works fine now